# How to find shortest path between two shapes?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Api in my application.

I draw two shapes on my Google map one is polygon and other is polyline.

I want to find shortest distance between two shapes.

I tried `google.map.sperical.computedistance()` but this only finds the total distance and not the shortest.

Can anyone tell me how to find shortest distance between two paths?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Distance Matrix service which might be what you want: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

There's also a corresponding webservice

Comment: You can check it. It might help you

Answer (score 0):

I would personally stay clear of the computed distance stuff unless you need the added functionality to justify the extra code weight.

As to an answer, just perform the distance calculation between all known points. You know all the points of both the polygon and the line. So just pick the one with the fewest points and start looping through the comparisons with one point of the initial piece and then move onto the next.

Keep a variable set as the shortest and every time you find one shorter, just update that variable.